# Module not found: Can't resolve 'supports-color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have an onboarding form component where I check if a user exsits in the database, if yes redirect to /activity and if not show the form.

`OnboardingForm.jsx`

```
'use client'

import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'
import { getUserByEmail } from '@/utils/user'
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'

export default async function OnboardingForm() {
  const { data: session } = useSession()

  if (!(await getUserByEmail(session.user.email))) {
    redirect('/activity')
  } else {
    return <form>{/* YOUR FORM GOES HERE       */}</form>
  }
}
```

Whenever I import my getUserByEmail, I get the below error.

Code for `getUserByEmail.js` is as below.

```
export async function getUserByEmail(email) {
  try {
    await connectDB()
    const user = await User.findOne({ email })

    if (!user) {
      console.log('User not found by that email.')
      return null
    }

    console.log('User found by that email.')
    return user
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Failed to fetch user:', error.message)
    return null
  }
}
```

`Module not found: Can't resolve 'supports-color'`

Whenever I remove the getUserByEmail import, the code works fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check  `await connectDB()` for a return error or success in connecting

Comment: No issues in connect db. It works perfectly fine with other functions. I have the same function being called the api and works without any issues.

Comment: I have narrowed down the issue, when I use 'use client' on my component I am unable to use the getUserByEmail function. Any thoughts?

Comment: Answer is in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76292961/check-email-exists-and-if-yes-forward-to-dashboard-page-in-nextjs