# Check email exists and if yes, forward to dashboard page in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I have the below code on my dashboard `page.jsx`

```
'use client'

import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'
import { getUserByEmail } from '@/utils/user'

export default async function DashboardPage() {
  const { data: session } = useSession()

  if (!(await getUserByEmail(session.user.email))) {
    redirect('/onboarding')
  } else {
    return <div>Welcome to Dashboard</div>
  }
}
```

`getUserByEmail.js` code is below.

```
export async function getUserByEmail(email) {
  try {
    if ((await getUsers()) === null) {
      console.log('No users in the database.')
      return null
    }

    await connectDB()
    const user = await User.findOne({ email })

    if (!user) {
      console.log('User not found by that email.')
      return null
    }

    console.log('User found by that email.')
    return user
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Failed to fetch user:', error.message)
    return null
  }
}
```

The above code doesn't run. I get a long error when compiling the code saying cannot find various modules. When I remove the `'use client'`, the error goes away. But I have to use `'use client'` because of the `useSession` hook.

What would be the best way to do this?

Thank you.

Error message below:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'supports-color' in '/Users/nadunperera/Projects/stash_ver_0.2/node_modules/debug/src'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/debug/src/node.js
./node_modules/debug/src/index.js
./node_modules/mquery/lib/mquery.js
./node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
./node_modules/mongoose/index.js
./models/User.js
./utils/user.js
./app/components/onboarding/OnboadingCheck.jsx
./app/components/onboarding/OnboardingForm.jsx

./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'kerberos' in '/Users/nadunperera/Projects/stash_ver_0.2/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
./node_modules/mongoose/index.js
./models/User.js
./utils/user.js
./app/components/onboarding/OnboadingCheck.jsx
./app/components/onboarding/OnboardingForm.jsx

./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@mongodb-js/zstd' in '/Users/nadunperera/Projects/stash_ver_0.2/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
./node_modules/mongoose/index.js
./models/User.js
./utils/user.js
./app/components/onboarding/OnboadingCheck.jsx
./app/components/onboarding/OnboardingForm.jsx

./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@aws-sdk/credential-providers' in '/Users/nadunperera/Projects/stash_ver_0.2/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
./node_modules/mongoose/index.js
./models/User.js
./utils/user.js
./app/components/onboarding/OnboadingCheck.jsx
./app/components/onboarding/OnboardingForm.jsx

./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'snappy' in '/Users/nadunperera/Projects/stash_ver_0.2/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
./node_modules/mongoose/index.js
./models/User.js
./utils/user.js
./app/components/onboarding/OnboadingCheck.jsx
./app/components/onboarding/OnboardingForm.jsx

./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'aws4' in '/Users/nadunperera/Projects/stash_ver_0.2/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/deps.js
./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
./node_modules/mongoose/index.js
./models/User.js
./utils/user.js
./app/components/onboarding/OnboadingCheck.jsx
./app/components/onboarding/OnboardingForm.jsx

./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js
./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/change_stream.js
./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
./node_modules/mongoose/index.js
./models/User.js
./utils/user.js
./app/components/onboarding/OnboadingCheck.jsx
./app/components/onboarding/OnboardingForm.jsx

./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'mongodb-client-encryption' in '/Users/nadunperera/Projects/stash_ver_0.2/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js
./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/change_stream.js
./node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/index.js
./node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
./node_modules/mongoose/index.js
./models/User.js
./utils/user.js
```

Comment: Can you put the error log in the question?

Comment: I just added it to the question. Thank you.

Comment: try adding for ex. `kerberos` in `next.config.js` like described here: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/transpilePackages and see if that error goes away, if not then try installing it `yarn add -D kerberos` or `npm i --save-dev kerberos`

Comment: no luck with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're running into a common issue when using Next.js with Mongoose or any other Node.js package that requires server-side dependencies. **The problem is that Next.js tries to bundle these dependencies for the client-side, but these packages are designed to work only in a Node.js environment.** Therefore, these server-side dependencies are not found when Next.js tries to bundle them for the client-side, leading to the error messages you're seeing.

The line `import { getUserByEmail } from '@/utils/user'` is causing Next.js to attempt to bundle the Mongoose code for the client-side, as `getUserByEmail` function is using Mongoose.

To fix the issue, you need to separate your client-side and server-side code. In Next.js, you can use API routes for server-side code. Instead of calling `getUserByEmail` directly in your component, create an API route (for example `/api/user`) and call that API route from your component.

Here's an example of how you could refactor your code:

First, create a new file in the `pages/api` directory. Let's call it `user.js`. This is where you will move your `getUserByEmail` function:

```js
// pages/api/user.js
import { connectDB } from '@/utils/db'
import User from '@/models/User'

export default async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await connectDB()
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.query.email })

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'User not found by that email.' })
    }

    return res.status(200).json(user)
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: error.message })
  }
}
```

Then, in your `DashboardPage`, instead of calling `getUserByEmail`, call the API route you just created:

```js
// pages/dashboard.js
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function DashboardPage() {
  const { data: session } = useSession()
  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUser = async () => {
      const res = await fetch(`/api/user?email=${session.user.email}`)
      if (res.status === 404) {
        router.push('/onboarding')
      }
    }

    if (session) {
      fetchUser()
    }
  }, [session])

  return <div>Welcome to Dashboard</div>
}
```

Please note that `useEffect` and `useRouter` are hooks from React and Next.js respectively. `useEffect` runs side-effects (in this case, fetching user data) after render, and `useRouter` allows you to manipulate the route.

This way, your Mongoose code will run only on the server-side, and you won't get errors about missing dependencies on the client-side.

Comment: This is perfect. I read the https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching#the-fetch-api as I am using App Router, documentation suggest to use Fetch in server components. Is there a way that we can improve your answer by using fetch in a server component?

Comment: @NadunPerera Fetch is suggested for outgoing HTTP requests. I do not think that it's appliable for your case since you use mongoose for DB queries.

Comment: This explanation was super useful. Thanks Samet.